# How to make user-id validator using regex with the condition that have only enligsh alpabet, number.etc

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make some regex validator for password.
Password can have only english alpahbet [a-z][A-Z], and number [0-9], and some specific symbol like -, _.
I tried make a regex condition as below. But this is not perfect for my case.

```
const password = "123" // true
const password = "abcd123" // false

const result = /^[0-9]*$/.test(password);
```

I want to make this condition.

```
const password = 'abcd1234' // true
const password = 'A!~' // false
const password = '123456' // true
const password = 'abcd_123' // true
const password = 'abcd-123' // true
```

How can I make these case for regex? Could you give me some advice? Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you were very close in your current implementation. Actually, what that one does is check if the string is made up of only numbers. Just adding valid characters inside those square brackets would be an easy fix. In fact his regex should solve your problem, but feel free to expand on it:

```
const result = /^[\da-zA-Z-,_]*$/.test(password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is probably:

```
valid = password => !/[^\w.,-]/.test(password)
valid('123') // true
valid('123#') // false
```

Note that `.` and `-` don't get escaped inside character class (`-` goes at the end) and `\w` === `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 0):

Just include all ranges on the `[]`

```js
testPassword = password => /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/.test(password);

test = password => console.log(`Testing ${password}: ${testPassword(password)}`);

test('abcd1234');
test('A!~');
test('123456');
test('abcd_123');
test('ABcd-123');
```

Comment: `a-zA-Z0-9_` is same as `\w`

Answer (score 0):

```py
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-,\._]{1,9}$

# a-z, A-Z, 0-9 range
# - _,. characters
# min length = 1, max length = 9
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: @BDL Sorry, that's true. I answered through my phone and doing the regular expression and testing it in regex101 was hard enough xd

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex you want.

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_,.]+$/`

```js
const tests = ['abcd1234', 'A!~', '123456', 'abcd_123', 'abcd-123'];
tests.forEach(testCase => console.log(testCase, /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_,.]+$/.test(testCase)));
```